# Object value 'addedToCart' is not updating globally in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, service, components

I'm trying to update the `addedToCart` value present in `bookArr` in books.service.ts. The problem is that it's not updating the value.

I'm trying to toggle the "Add to Cart" button present in **book.component.html** to "Remove from Cart" by retrieving the `addedToCart` value. As the value is not updating globally I'm not able to toggle the button.

I'm a beginner. If you know the answer kindly take extra efforts to try to explain me conceptually what's going on.

cart.service.ts

```
export class CartService {

  cart: Book[] = [];

  constructor(private bookService: BooksService) { }

  addToCart(book: Book) {
    book.addedToCart = true;
    this.bookService.updateCartValue(book);
    this.cart.push(book);
    
  }
  
  get() {
    return this.cart;
  }
  
  remove(book: Book) {
    book.addedToCart = false;
    this.bookService.updateCartValue(book);
    this.cart = this.cart.filter((b) => b != book);
    
  }
}
```

books.service.ts

```
export class BooksService {
  
  bookArr: any;
  
  constructor() { }

  getBooks() {
    this.bookArr = [
      {
        sno: 1, 
        name: 'A good book',
        author: 'author 1',
        image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/814L+vq01mL._AC_UY327_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg',
        amount: 400,
        addedToCart: false
      },
      {
        sno: 2,          
        name: 'A great book',
        author: 'author 2',
        image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41HrvsyKdBL._AC_UY327_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg',
        amount: 500,
        addedToCart: false
      },
      {
        sno: 3,
        name: 'A superb book',
        author: 'author 3',
        image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71B4h-dSVzL._AC_UY327_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg',
        amount: 700,
        addedToCart: false
      },
      {
        sno: 4,
        name: 'A terrific book',
        author: 'author 4',
        image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61Iz2yy2CKL._AC_UY327_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg',
        amount: 1000,
        addedToCart: false
      },
      {
        sno: 5,
        name: 'A mind-blowing book',
        author: 'author 5',
        image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71PpwN9ZsuL._AC_UY327_FMwebp_QL65_.jpg',
        amount: 1400,
        addedToCart: false
      }
    ]
    
    return this.bookArr;
  }

  updateCartValue(book: Book) {
    console.log(book.addedToCart);
    this.bookArr[book.sno -1].addedToCart = book.addedToCart;
    console.log(this.bookArr[book.sno].addedToCart);
    
  }
}
```

book.component.ts

```
export class BookComponent {
  @Input() book: Book;
  
  bookArr: Book[] = [];
  
  constructor(private cartService: CartService, private bookService: BooksService) {
    this.book = this.bookService.getBooks();
    console.log(this.book);
    
  }
  


  addCart() {
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.book);
    console.log(this.book);
    
  }

  removeCart() {
    this.cartService.remove(this.book);
  }
}
```

Comment: what decorators do you have on your services? ie: `@Injectable`?

Comment: Services are singleton so the instance are the same across the application. Post your entire code of each section please. Or build a StackBlitz example :)